# wxpython: Replacing the old content- wx.SplitterWindow object split horizontally in two panels, with another completely new panel

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to build this GUI tool in wxpython as part of my project. I have a basic frame that has a splitter window(wx.SplitterWindow object), split horizontally. When the application is first opened, it will show just the splitter window with some text. I also have a menu that houses various menu-items that are binded to the respective event-handlers. Now, when I click on a particular menu-item for the first time, I need a new wx.Notebook object to be created with a page that hosts the info related to that event-handler, on top of the already existing content in the frame (the wx.SplitterWindow object). Typically, I would want a new panel to be created on top of the old content, that will be the parent to the notebook object. Every subsequent click of a menu-item should create a new page in the notebook. May I know how this can be achieved?

Here are the necessary code snippets, that I have written, but ofc I have gone horribly wrong somewhere:

## This code creates the initial splitter window composed of two panels:

```
    self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, id = wx.ID_ANY)
    self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self.splitter, id = wx.ID_ANY)
    self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self.splitter, id = wx.ID_ANY)
    self.panel1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.LIGHT_GREY)
    self.splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panel1, self.panel2)
```

## Code for the first menu-item click event:

```
def displayNodes(self,event):
    if hasattr(self, "notebook") == False: #If the notebook object has not been already created
        #create notebook if it does not exitst already. This script should be present in every event handler
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.notebook = NotebookDemo(self.panel)
        #creating vertical sizer for the notebook
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
    self.nodesname = "nodes"
    self.nodesinstance = wx.SingleInstanceChecker(self.nodesname)
    if self.nodesinstance.IsAnotherRunning():
        self.notebook.ChangeSelection(self.nodesindex)
    else:
        #creating a tab
        self.nodesTab = TabPanel(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.AddPage(self.nodesTab, "List of all the nodes")
        self.nodes = wx.ListBox(self.nodesTab, 11, (10,40), (200,130), self.nodeslist, wx.LB_SINGLE)
        self.nodesindex = self.notebook.GetPageCount() - 1
        self.notebook.SetSelection(self.nodesindex)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.OnShowPopup)
```

PS: My knowledge of wxpython is limited, and I am still learning! Would be more than happy if the objective can be achieved in a much elegant way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the methodology that I talk about in my panel switching tutorial: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/

Or instead of replacing the panel, you could Show/Hide Notebook objects, check which one is active and add tabs to the active one.